# How do you set the "socketTimeoutMS" option using the deprecated 'Mongo' class in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

Using the MongoClient class in PHP, it is possible to set the option 'socketTimeoutMS' to a specific value, extending PHP's wait time for results from MongoDB.

For example, for a 5-minute response wait time (in MS)

```
$cli = new MongoClient($connection_string, array(
  'socketTimeoutMS' => 5*60*1000
));
```

How do you do this using the deprecated Mongo class in PHP?

Note we are on a host that uses the deprecated Mongo class (not MongoClient class), hence the q.

Answer (score 1):

The Mongo class extends MongoClient and simply adds deprecation notices, so any options supported by MongoClient would also work with Mongo. The Mongo class does not add any additional functionality.

> Note we are on a host that uses the deprecated Mongo class (not MongoClient class)

I'm not sure if you mean to say that the application is using the Mongo class or that the installed extension is so old that MongoClient is not even available (before 1.3.0).

The `socketTimeoutMS` option was introduced in 1.3.4, per the [MongoClient changelog](http://phpweb.local/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php#refsect1-mongoclient.construct-changelog). In earlier versions, there was a `timeout` constructor option for Mongo and MongoClient, which was later renamed to `connectTimeoutMS` (i.e. not what you want).

Socket timeouts for all database operations were originally handled by setting the [`MongoCursor::$timeout`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php#mongocursor.props.timeout) static property. In the current version of the driver, we still check `MongoCursor::$timeout` for BC reasons, but we do emit a deprecation notice if it is used; however, if you're on some version before 1.3.4, that's likely what you want.

If you would like to customize timeouts on a per-query basis, you can also use [`MongoCursor::timeout()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.timeout.php). And lastly, if you're using MongoDB 2.6+, you should look into use server-side timeouts (via [`MongoCursor::maxTimeMS()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.maxtimems.php) and the [`maxTimeMS`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/terminate-running-operations/#maxtimems) command option. Server-side timeouts are generally better, as they do not result in the client abruptly terminating the operation and leaving it running on the server.

Comment: Thanks @jmikola, but this doesn't answer the question. To restate: 

How, using the deprecated 'Mongo' client in PHP, do you set the 'socketTimeoutMS' option?  Is it simply:

`$cli = new Mongo($connection_string, array(
  'socketTimeoutMS' => 5*60*1000
));`

Comment: "The Mongo class extends MongoClient and simply adds deprecation notices, so any options supported by MongoClient would also work with Mongo" should have answered the question. I elaborated beyond that because it wasn't clear from the OP what version of the driver you were using. Saying that the "host uses the deprecated Mongo class" lead me to believe that you were pre-1.3.0 (when MongoClient was introduced), and any versions prior to 1.3.4 wouldn't have a "socketTimeoutMS" option on the connection class.